# Failed to configure a datasource. Postgresql

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to use postgresql in my project, but keep getting this error.

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).
```

I´ve uninstalled and reinstalled pgAgent, pgJDBC and postgreSQL itself. i tought it was some problem in my machine, so i've restored it to factory and i keep getting the same error.

This is my application.properties

```
!<--Conexión a base de datos-->
spring.jpa.database=postgresql
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/demo
!<--Credencales base de datos-->
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=admin
```

This is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.4</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.novae</groupId>
    <artifactId>red_social</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>red_social</name>
    <description>Red social con CRUD de amigos</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Seguridad -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I've made a blank project and the error apears when i use the jpa dependency.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

It's finally working, i don´t know what really happend, i've restored to factory again and installed one by one (JDK 8, postgres) and restarted my pc, after that i've made a new project and it works. I still don't know what happend.

Thanks everyone for trying to help me.

Comment: `5432` port is missing in `application.properties` it should be similar to this: `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/demo`

Comment: I've put it, but i keep getting the same error. besides in previous projects i used it without the port and it worked.

Comment: you get that error when: spring can not find the `application.properties` (or yml) in the `resources` directory or Datasource configs are missing, which you already have.